# How to load multiple components in one place but data should not change which user has entered

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope, angular2-routing

I have 3 components `PersonalInfoComponent` , `EducationalInfoComponent` and `ExperienceComponent`.
I am loading all these components in `ResumeComponent`.

When user enters some info using form in `PersonalInfoComponent` and goes to `EducationalInfoComponent` and again clicks on `PersonalInfoComponent`, data is getting refresh because `Components` are loading each time and resetting a form.

I need, user just fill all the info in each components and submit all data in one click.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you store the user input?

Comment: I don&#39;t want to store anywhere. I have filled the form in any of those components, its should remain there if I am coming again on that component

Comment: @ShaileshJain, as you said your components are refreshing , then you try saving data in the local storage or in the indexed DB too

Comment: Yes,This thing I can do, but each time I have to bind data if user comes to that component.  Like as a resume creating application, you filled all info and then save.

Comment: the "data" must belong to "ResumeComponent" (it's not necesary then use localstore) you must interact parent child using @ Input and @ Output to "send" the data to the parent, see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

In your ResumeComponent initialize three variables **personalInfo, educationalInfo and experienceInfo**, and pass them as **input** to your **PersonalInfoComponent, EducationalInfoComponent and ExperienceComponent** respectively. You store your form data in the child components in these variables and on **ngDestroy** of each component you **emit an event to send that data to your parent(ResumeComponent)** and update your variable in parent component. If you do so then your data will not be lost even if you move from one component to another.
I hope my answer was helpful. :)